# Testing ios app with great firewall of China

Tags: ios, great-firewall-of-china

I have an existing iOS app that is available on the appstore and works well except that users tell me (via appstore reviews) that it (sometimes) does not work in China.

Since the app uses http webservices to a european server and streaming video using wistia I strongly belief its because communication is being blocked by the great firewall of China.

I would like to test this somehow.
What would be the best way to test my iOS app here in Europe (Belgium) as if it would be sitting behind the great  firewall of China?

Answer (score 6):

I would say the best way to test this would be to VPN **into** china. That way you can test whether your app's traffic is being blocked by the great firewall.

Here is a website which lists a few VPNs that could do the job:
https://www.vpndada.com/vpn-into-china/

Comment: Interesting checked purevpn, they have an ios app. I am assuming this would allow me to connect the ios device to the gfoc and test like that. Have you ever tried this?

Comment: That should change the VPN in the iOS settings and allow you to test it. If not then you can do it directly in the phone's settings